# Reasons for Solace CLIENT_CLIENT_DISCONNECT_MQTT

Tags: solace

Recently one of our MQTT clients is disconnected by Solace quite often in our Development Solace appliance but there is no issue for the same client in Test Solace appliance.  We have no clue why this happens.

Upon checking Solace event log, I noticed there are quite a number of records in the event log for CLIENT_CLIENT_DISCONNECT_MQTT event.  There are different reasons given for the event.  The unique reasons I filtered out from the event log are listed below.  May I know what could be the causes of these reasons?

Following are the reasons for CLIENT_CLIENT_DISCONNECT_MQTT event I filtered from the event log:

1. Client Disconnect Received
2. Forced Logout
3. Peer TCP Closed
4. Peer TCP Reset

I tried to think of the possible causes.  For (1), does that mean client performs a normal MQTT disconnect call?  For (2), could it be triggered by our backend application which issues SEMP command to disconnect the client as we do have such a function at the backend application? As for (3) and (4), I am not sure under what circumstances it happens as our MQTT client does not do anything specifically that could cause a disconnection to happen.

Is there any documentation of the reasons and the explanation for the causes of them?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer in Solace syslog documentation, https://docs.solace.com/System-and-Software-Maintenance/Monitoring-Events-Using-Syslog.htm

In addition, I did a simple experiment and found the following:

- Client Disconnect Received: when client does a mqtt disconnect call
- Forced Logout: (a) when Solace disconnects a client if duplicate client ID is used; (b) When SEMP command is used to disconnect the client
  Peer
- Peer TCP Reset: when the client 's connection is interrupted (e.g. the client program is killed by pressing ctrl+c)